# ways of using midi events to make a player move in pygame

Tags: python, events, pygame, midi

I have made some little games with the pygame module and it had been fun. However, right now i´m trying to move the character with a piano via midi using pygame.midi. there´s the problem. I did it but not in the way i wanted to because
the character moves sometimes and other it doesn´t. I think i know where is the problem: If i understand correctly, the pygame.event.get() function "catch" the events always, it does not matter when (inside the main loop of the game), so i think that with my code this is not happening, i mean, i believe that the player not always do what is supposed to do because the midi input has to be in a specific "time" not as pygame.event.get(). I looked into the pygame documentation and there seems to be a function that does the trick: pygame.midi.midis2events(), but i don´t know how to use it.The question is just:
How can i move the character through the piano via midi with pygame in order that the character moves everytime?

```
import pygame as pg, pygame.midi 

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60

BLACK = (0,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)


pg.init()
pg.midi.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pg.display.set_caption('STACKOVERFLOW_EXAMPLE_MIDI')
clock = pg.time.Clock()

running = True

inp = pg.midi.Input(1)
x = WIDTH//2
y = HEIGHT//2
speedx = 0

midi_list = []

while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    if inp.poll():
        midi_value = inp.read(1000)[0][0][1]
        if midi_value==57:
            midi_list.append(midi_value)
            if len(midi_list)==1:
                speedx = -1
            else:
                speedx = 0
                midi_list = []
        if midi_value == 63:
            running = False
    x = x+speedx
    screen.fill(BLUE)
    pg.draw.rect(screen,BLACK,[x,y,50,60])
    pg.display.update()
    pg.display.flip()

pg.quit()
```

I need that the player moves to the left (or to the right) when the piano´s key A3 (a specific note) is being pressed and that the player stops moving when
the key has been released. In this particular fragment of the code, but also to do things like press a piano´s key an shoot one bullet regardless of whether is being pressed or not, in short, to do the same things i can do with the keyboard events.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of the problem.

Comment: refer this: https://github.com/xamox/pygame/blob/master/examples/midi.py

Comment: ok, i think i have a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example!

Comment: Biswa_9937 thank you for the link, i´ve seen it already and is not working, and i don´t know why, i don´t understand the code quit well, specially the part after i.poll() in the input_main function, and also the [pygame.midi.MIDIIN] is not working aparently because it never enter...

Answer (score 0):

ok! i found and answer that works well for the time being:

```
if inp.poll():
    s(0.1)
    midi_values = inp.read(1000)

    for midi in midi_values:
        midi_value = midi[0][1]
        #Movement to the left
        if midi_value==57:
            midi_list.append(midi_value)
            if len(midi_list)==1:
                speedx = -50
```

Modifying the code in order to iterate the list midi_values gives me the correct input-output response without the inestability which i experienced. Also i did introduce a sleep(0.1) delay and works well without to much cpu use. I found the answer here: 
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/36dxu9/python_whileloop_cpu_demanding/

The only problem which i find now is that the pygame window stops with the message no responde (doesn´t respond or something similar) and it stops working.
For example the cube which i´m moving with the keys of the piano doesn´t do anything but the key to close the program does work fine!!